# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to handle a plan in a MEAN Stack application. When I call findOne, I'm getting this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ '576df16eed10c2fccbcbd60c' ]\" at path \"_id\""
```

This is how I'm doing this:

```
Plan.findOne({_id: planId}, function(err, plan){ //do something });
```

I noticed that when I put the id as a string (like below), everything works fine.

```
Plan.findOne({_id: '576df16eed10c2fccbcbd60c'}, function(err, plan)
```

So, I console the `planId`:

```
console.log('planId: ' + planId + ' | ' + typeof planId);
Output: planId: [ '576df16eed10c2fccbcbd60c' ] | object
```

I've been trying stuff that I found here in SO but anything could help me to solve this problem :/

Comment: can you show me how sent and received planId ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `planId` is an array.

can you try with `planId[0]` ?

```
Plan.findOne({_id: planId[0]}, function(err, plan){ //do something });
```

or

```
Plan.findOne({_id: new ObjectId(planId[0])}, function(err, plan){ //do something });
```

Comment: ObjectId was undefined. So I tried `planId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(planId[0]);` but it gives me another error: "Plan not found". I'm sure this id is correct.

Comment: After convert to ObjectId the output for `planId` is: `577fc3002eccc12d154631e1` and the type still `object`.

Comment: Plan not found is strange; are you sure you are including (requiring) the Plan model?

Comment: Yes! `Plan = mongoose.model('Plan');`. I noticed that when I try to convert to ObjectId like the comments above, the function gives me another ID. This is why I can't find the plan. There is a way to convert for ObjectId maintaining the initial ID? Actually I can handle this with a workaround, just removing the `[""]` with replace. But I don't want to let this into the code.